# Changing global variable from onCreate method

Tags: java, android, global-variables

This may seem like a small problem, but I don't know how to deal with it.

I have created a string-array in an xml file. Next, I want to import this array into a String[], and this is how I do it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.releases);

    // array from XML
    String[] rlsMixTitleArr0 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.releasesMixTitle);
    rlsMixTitleArr = rlsMixTitleArr0;

    // rest of program...
}
```

`rlsMixTitleArr` is declared above this method as:

```
static String[] rlsMixTitleArr = new String[] {};
```

I have tested via a Toast message that the global variable rlsMixTitleArr does indeed get updated correctly. However, the problem is that when I try to access rlsMixTitleArr from another method (not onCreate), it's like it has not been updated at all, and it's just an empty array (since it's declared this way at the top). You should think that onCreate is what happens first when the program starts, and therefore the global variable would be updated (and could be used by other methods). And as far as I know, you can't get something from resources above the onCreate method. So I'm stuck now.

How do I get it working?

Comment: Which other method are you trying to access this from? (can't imagine  one being invoked before onCreate()). Also any particular reason your not directly loading the array into 'rlsMixTitleArr'?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead creating an accessor for the static array, with a check that it's been populated. That way the array gets created on demand instead of in an event handler that *should* create it before you want it.

```
static String[] rlsMixTitleArr = null;


public static String[] getRlsMixTitleArray(){
    if ( rlsMixTitleArray == null ) {
        rlsMixTitleArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.releasesMixTitle);
    }

    return rlsMixTitleArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. First of all, I had to remove 'static' from the method to get it error-free. Second of all, I get a NullPointerException when I call this method.

Comment: Ah ... getResources() is an instance method, then? Why not then call the array population line in the object's constructor?  // Edit - nope, that still wouldn't solve the looking for it before it's created problem. Can you make getResources() static?

Comment: I would maybe go another way -- get rid of the statics if possible. Does rlxMixTitleArr need to be static?

Comment: @Angie I don't think I can change getResources in any way since it's a built-in method. Not saying I'm 100% sure though.

Comment: @mouser No I don't think it needs to be static. Right now I have removed everything static with rlsMixTitleArr, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @eightx2: If `getResources()` is not a static method, then probably it should not be used to initialize static resources... have you checked the source of that method? Is your `rlsMixTitleArray` really a variable with a value that is global for whole application?

Comment: @eightx2: In which context / from which method do you try to access that array when it's null, then?

Comment: @mouser Well, first of all I have in my onCreate a GridView with an onItemClickListener. When an image is clicked, a method called setData is called. It is in this method that I call `rlsMixTitleArr` (either directly, or indirectly via the method suggested in the answer above).

Comment: @eightx2 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1333/discussion-between-mouser-and-eightx2)

Comment: mouser helped me sorting out this issue in the chat. Here is what was done: `private String[] rlsMixTitleArr = null;` is put above the onCreate method. Calling `rlsMixTitleArr = c.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.releasesMixTitle);` from the previously mentioned method setData() works.